# Fortune 500 CEOs/executive boards

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a file that contains either all the CEOs or preferably the executive boards. Any file format is okay. I just can't find anything or any file that has this data, nor do any of the APIs I've looked through offer this.

Comment: Be aware that Fortune 500 is just a ranking by Fortune Business magazine. It doesn't map onto any legal definitions nor any government datasets. It's hard to use it as a valid datasource because the rankings and constituent companies constantly change. Worse, the actual ranking system used by Fortune is not public and contains, by their own admission, rather a lot of subjectivity on their part. SEC filings are your best bet for publicly traded companies.

Comment: @TechZen thanks for the info, I was also going to look into SEC filings but thanks for explaining how the Fortune 500 works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For publicly traded companies, Google Finance or another similar site will list the officers and directors. For example, GOOG: https://www.google.com/finance?q=google
- For private companies, I have found investing.businessweek.com to be a good source. For example, Socrata: http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=41354884

Either of these could be screen-scraped within reason or maybe they even have APIs.

Answer (score 3):

With a quick Google Search, I found these datasets:

1) Wikipedia [List of chief executive officers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chief_executive_officers)

2) [Fortune 500](http://fortune.com/fortune500/wal-mart-stores-inc-1/) This is not a dataset per se, but you can find the CEO in the infobox. Maybe you can find a way to extract the info from there.